# How to convert T matrix to Z matrix in two port network?

Tags: math, network, matrix

How can I transform a T matrix to become a Z matrix for a two-port network?

I found the following conversion to get the T matrix from Z matrix from here: [Two-Port Parameter Conversions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/network_theory/network_theory_twoport_parameter_conversions.htm)

> **Step 7** - Therefor, the **T parameters matrix** is
>  $$\begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ C & D \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{Z_{11}}{Z_{21}} & \frac{Z_{11}Z_{22}-Z_{12}Z_{21}}{Z_{21}}\\
> \frac{1}{Z_{21}} & \frac{Z_{22}}{Z_{21}} \end{bmatrix}$$

But I would like to get the opposite of this. To go from T matrix to Z matrix

Comment: Just do some algebra. If you look at it for a minute you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Comment: This [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/network_theory/network_theory_twoport_networks.htm) clearly provides the definitions of each type. Since they already provide you with the answer for \$Z\rightarrow T\$ and from the page I've linked you know the independent definitions of \$T\$ and \$Z\$, you should be easily able to see how they arrived at the transformation they provided on the link you gave. Knowing that much, it should be a walk in the park to do the reverse. Do you follow how they derived \$Z\rightarrow T\$? If so, there are no problems. If not, focus on *their* derivation first.

Answer (score 1):

[image: table of conversion from T to Z and Z to T]

This [document](https://empossible.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/IEEETransMTT_v42_n2_p205-Parameter-Conversion-Tables.pdf) from ieee has a bunch of tables for such conversions, and

Comment: It looks like you started a useful answer but didn't finish.  Can you complete the answer, and include a summary of anything from key links?